# Heap Space Error

Tags: hadoop, heap-memory, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to execute a job and I am getting Heap Space Error.
After make some tests, I realize (maybe) the problem is the custom key size. (the mapper out key/ reduce input key)

First I test:
1. Custom Key holding only one Long. This not cause heap space error problems.
2. Custom Key holding 3 Longs. This cause heap space problem.

I really dont understand what is the real relantionship between heap size and the custom key size.

Is there any relationship between them?

Thanks,